# Thyristor latching current and holding resistance

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, thyristor

Is there a formula for calculating the latching current of a thyristor and the resistance of the thyristor after it forward conducts and I_gate becomes 0? I couldn't find anything online; the tutorials just describe how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mix peaches and apples. Latching current is a parameter, nothing to calculate. You can calculate the equivalent resistance from forward voltage drop.

Answer (score 4):

No there is no formula, it's a characteristic of the device and some guidance can be found in the datasheet (eg. [2N5064](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/308/2N5060_D-110409.pdf)  datasheet).

[image]

[image]

As always, there can be considerable variation from unit to unit, as well as with temperature.

Also note that the temperature curve is *normalized* and no typical number is given at all, so a holding current of (say) 0.2mA would meet the specifications. This can have consequences to your design. It's probably of the order of the gate trigger current.

---

Thyristors do not have on resistance per se, they have a voltage drop which depends (in a very nonlinear way) on current. Again, the device datasheet is your reference. For many purposes you could assume the 'on' voltage drop is constant at around a volt. You could convert that into a "resistance" but it would have little meaning and less utility since it would only be valid at a single current.

[image]